# КТ -какой род она или оно

Tags: род

КТ, МРТ-она или оно? Необходимо КТ или необходима КТ?

Comment: Пишите значения аббревиатур.  Не сразу и сообразишь, о чем речь.

Answer (score 4):

Компьтерная и магнитно-резонансная **томография**. Главное слово "томография", соответственно женский род, - "Необходим**а** КТ".